# Can't assign to array, custom function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that creates and returns array:

```
Function test() 
     Dim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant
     Set resultArray(1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("B1:B1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("C1:C1000")

     Set resultArray(1, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("D1:D1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("E1:E1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("F1:F1000")


     test=resultArray
End Function

Sub testTestFunction()
     Dim storedRanges() As Variant 'works fine
     'Dim storedRanges(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant 'error on the next line
     storedRanges=test()  
     MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

I try to methods of initialization `Dim storedRanges() As Variant` and `Dim storedRanges(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant`, and only the former works.  Why does this happen?

Comment: Your code should not even compile, you are defining twice the same variable (storedRanges)

Comment: @Vincent G, Fixed that, now it compiles.

Comment: Ok, given that it compile, it is working here. You are storing a reference to a range in the (1,1) position of a (3,2) sized array.

Comment: @Vincent G, does it matter? The rest of array is just empty

Comment: When assigning arrays, the left side of the assignment must be variable, you can't have a statically sized array on the left side of an assignment.

Comment: @Vincent G, I stored ranges to the rest of the array and it still gives error.

Comment: You are declaring an array and then setting an element of the array to be an object. When you use **`SET`**, its not an array anymore, its an object. As you haven't said what the actual error is, I'm presuming that you want an array and not an object in an array?

Comment: @Zac,The actual arror is `Can't assign to array`, it's in the title. I want to have an array of objects.

Comment: This is an array of `Range` objects and hence the need for the `Set` statement. Have you tried with a dynamic array? `Dim resultArray() As Variant` and `ReDim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Passing the array to be populated to the procedure as argument `ByRef` may fit your needs:

```vb
Sub Test()

     Dim storedRanges(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Object

     PutRanges storedRanges

End Sub

Sub PutRanges(q() As Object)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup")
        Set q(1, 1) = .Range("A1:A1000")
        Set q(2, 1) = .Range("B1:B1000")
        Set q(3, 1) = .Range("C1:C1000")
        Set q(1, 2) = .Range("D1:D1000")
        Set q(2, 2) = .Range("E1:E1000")
        Set q(3, 2) = .Range("F1:F1000")
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a dynamic array, instead of a statically allocated one:

```
Function test() As Variant()
     Dim resultArray() As Variant
     ReDim resultArray(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
     Set resultArray(1, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("A1:A1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("B1:B1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("C1:C1000")

     Set resultArray(1, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("D1:D1000")
     Set resultArray(2, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("E1:E1000")
     Set resultArray(3, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("setup").Range("F1:F1000")


     test = resultArray
End Function

Sub testTestFunction()
     Dim storedRanges() As Variant 'works fine
     'Dim storedRanges(1 To 3, 1 To 2) As Variant 'error on the next line
     storedRanges = test()
     MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

The results are what you would expect.